# use grep to find an entry in the $PATH variable

Tags: design-patterns, path, grep, matching

I have found many answers to using grep to search for the value in a variable within the contents of a file but not finding a particluar string in the actual contents of the $PATH variable. I'm on a mac and was trying to determine if "brew" was in my PATH and thought surely I can just use grep to do this... and I'm sure it's possible but nothing I've tried works so can someone please enlighten me? The following was what I thought would work but it just lists the contents of the PATH variable.

```
grep brew "${PATH}"
```

I also tried

```
grep brew -- "${PATH}"
```

which just did the same thing. What am I missing?

Comment: `grep STRING <<<"$PATH"`   Better output:  `tr ':' '\n' <<<"$PATH"|grep STRING`

Answer (score 1):

1. **Where is my binary located?**

Assume you are searching for the binary `brew`, where is it located? The answer here is to make use of `which`. Which will print the full path of the executable that would have been executed when entered on the shell prompt. It will do this by searching for an executable or script in the directories listed in `PATH`:

```
$ which brew
```

If you want to list all entries, i.e. sometimes directories mask others, you can use the `--all` flag:

```
$ which --all brew
```

2. **Is there a path-entry in path that matches the regular expression `ere`:**

```
$ awk -v RS=":" '/ere/' <<<$PATH
```